# Poor results using Sphinx 4 speech recognition platform

Tags: java, android, real-time, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I would like to develop a simple android based application, that operates as follows:

Listenning to the outside voices, and once the 'Time' word is recognized, the smartphone should pronounce the current time.

In order to achieve that goal, I was looking for java based library for speech recognition, that compatiable with the android platform, and found [Sphinix 4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4) platform.

However, I tried to experiment with the above library on my PC, but got very poor results. (0% success)

My code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration
            .setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");

    configuration
            .setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
    configuration
            .setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
    
    Microphone micro = new Microphone(44100, 16, true, false);
    
    micro.startRecording();

    StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(
            configuration);

    // Simple recognition with generic model
    recognizer.startRecognition(micro.getStream());
    SpeechResult result;
    while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {

        System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n", result.getHypothesis());

    }
    recognizer.stopRecognition();
    micro.stopRecording();
}
```

}

I will be glad for suggestions.

**EDIT:**

According to the recommendations below, I changed the bits rate to 16khz, and got slightly better result.

However, after changing `StreamSpeechRecognizer` to `LiveSpeechRecognizer`, I got unsupported exception:

```
 javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
```

**EDIT 2:**

I want to detect only one word(phrase): 'Time'.
May be my approach to use Speech Recognition is wrong?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out:

What I was looking for is [Keyword Spotting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_spotting), rather than general Speech Recognition.

I found that the [Pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) library is pretty accurate for my needs.

Comment: Hello did you implement your application ?

Comment: Partly. I got the impression that it is too heavy to run on a mobile continuously at the background. My battery got low very fast.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample to recognize audio from microphone is provided in [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4). Proper code uses LiveSpeechRecognizer. Your code is not going to work because you use 44.1khz sample rate in microphone, this rate is not supported by recognizer.

Also, sphinx4 is too resource hungry to run on Android, it is not possible to use it there. CMUSphinx project provides Pocketsphinx on Android library specifically designed for mobile applications. This library described in another [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid).

Comment: I want to test on PC, and shift to android. Look my edit, thanks.